# thoughts on a database connection class

Tags: php, mysql, connection

I have a simple database class that basically encompasses the functions below, so I decided to make discreet classes to do the same thing, my question specifically is what functionality would I need in the user and password classes to be ready for a production environment

```
$db = new DB;
$link = $db->connect()->getLink();

class DB {

    public $connection = array();

    public function __construct() {
        return $this;
    }

    public function connect($host=null, $user=null, $pass=null, $database=null) {
        $this->connection = new Connection($host, $user, $pass, $database);
        $this->connection->connect();
        $this->link = $this->connection->getLink();
        if ($this->connection->ping()) {
            if (!is_null($database)) {
                if (!$this->connection->databaseConnect($database)) {
                    throw new\Exception('Unable to connect to the server.');
                }
            }
        }else{
            throw new \Exception('Unable to connect to the server.');
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function getLink() {
        return $this->link;
    }

}

class Connection {

    protected $chost='localhost';
    protected $cuser='guest';
    protected $cpass='password';
    protected $cdatabase='PROFORDABLE';

    function __construct($host=null, $user=null, $pass=null, $database=null) {

        $host = !is_null($host) ? $host : $this->chost;
        $user = !is_null($user) ? $user : $this->cuser;
        $password = !is_null($pass) ? $pass : $this->cpass;
        $database = !is_null($database) ? $database : $this->cdatabase;

        $this->set('host', $host)->set('user', $user)->set('password', $password)->set('database', $database);
        return $this;
    }

    public function connect() {
        $link = mysqli_connect($this->host->getHost(), $this->user->getUser(), $this->password->getPassword());
        if (!is_object($link)) {
            throw new \Exception("An error has occurred while connecting to the server.");
        }
        $this->link = $link;
    }

    public function databaseConnect($database) {
        if (!mysqli_select_db($this->getLink(), $database)) {
            throw new \Exception("Unable to select the database.");
        }
    }

    public function getLink() {
        return $this->link;
    }

    public function ping() {
        if (mysqli_ping($this->link)) {
            return TRUE;
        }
        return FALSE;
    }

    public function set($name, $param) {
        if (!isset($name) || !isset($param)) return $this;
        $class = __NAMESPACE__.'\\'.ucwords($name);
        $this->$name = new $class($param);
        return $this;
    }

    public function get($name) {
        $getfunc = 'get'.ucwords($name);
        return $this->$name->$getFunc();
    }

}

class Host {
    public function __construct($host) {
        $this->setHost($host);
    }
    public function setHost($host) {
        $this->host = $host;
    }
    public function getHost() {
        return $this->host;
    }
}

class User {

    public function __construct($user) {
        $this->setUser($user);
    }

    public function setUser($user) {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function getUser() {
        return $this->user;
    }

}

class Password {

    public function __construct($password) {
        $this->setPassword($password);
    }

    public function setPassword($password) {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function getPassword() {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function sha($value) {
        return sha1($value);

    }

}

class guestPassword extends Password {
    const PASSWORD='password';
    public function __construct() {
        return PASSWORD;
    }
}

class Database {

    public function __construct($database) {
        $this->setDatabase($database);
    }

    public function setDatabase($database) {
        $this->database = $database;
    }

    public function getDatabase() {
        return $this->database;
    }

}

class Query {


}
```

Comment: Why not just mysqli in object mode directly?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the `DB` class just holds the connection as well. It's over-design to make a separate connection class.

I'd worry more about the API of `DB` than the internals.

Comment: what specifically do you mean api?

Comment: The interface. The public functions of `DB`.

Answer (score 0):

any help on keeping track of multiple connections??

```
class DB {

public $connections = array();
public $threads = array();
public $lastThread=null;

public function __construct() {
    $this->connect();
    return $this;
}

public function connect($host=null,$user=null,$pass=null,$db=null) {
    $connection = new Connection($host, $user, $pass, $db);
    if (!$connection->ping() || !$connection->databaseConnect($connection->get('database'))) {
        throw new \Exception('ping or database select problem');
    }

    $threadId = mysqli_thread_id($connection->getLink());
    $this->connections[$threadId] = $connection;
    $this->threads[] = $threadId;
    $this->lastThread = $threadId;
    return $this;
}

public function getLink($threadId=null) {
    if (is_null($threadId)) {
        if (!isset($this->lastThread)
        return $this->connections[$this->lastThread]->getLink();

    }else{
        return $this->connections[$threadId]->getLink();
    }
    }

}

class Connection {

public $link;
public $host='localhost';
public $user='guest';
public $pass='password';
public $database='PROFORDABLE';

function __construct($host=null, $user=null, $pass=null, $database=null) {
    if (!is_null($host)) $this->host = $host;
    if (!is_null($user)) $this->user = $user;
    if (!is_null($pass)) $this->pass = $pass;
    if (!is_null($database)) $this->database = $database;
    $this->connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass);
    $this->databaseConnect($this->database);
    return $this;
}

public function connect() {
    $link = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass);
    if (!is_object($link)) {
        throw new \Exception("Not object");
    }
    $this->link = $link;
}

public function databaseConnect($database=null) {
    if (!is_null($database)) $this->database = $database;
    if (!mysqli_select_db($this->getLink(), $this->database)) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

public function getLink() {
    return $this->link;
}

public function ping() {
    if (mysqli_ping($this->link)) {
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

public function set($param, $value) {
    $this->$param = $value;
}

public function get($param) {
    return $this->$param;
}

}

$db = new DB;
$link = $db->getLink();
$res = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT TITLE, DESCRIPTION FROM PRO_CONTENT ORDER BY DATE ASC LIMIT 3');
$content=array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $content[] = $row;
}

var_dump($content);
```